# Write Files to Azure Server from Another Azure Server Using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I had two azure server(Web Apps). I had write code to upload image file to same server.

Below is the code :

```
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_base64String);
  string path = Server.MapPath("../../assets/Upload/");

  FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
  file.Directory.Create();

  File.WriteAllBytes(path + "Test.jpg"),
```

This code is perfectly work for same server. How should i write same file on another server.

Now i need to write that file from Azure Server A to Azure Server B.

Comment: What do you mean by *Server A*  and *Server B*? Are you  referring to multiple instances of a web app (e.g. 2 instances of `myapp.azurewebsites.net`)? Or are you talking about copying files from `myapp1.azurewebsites.net` to `myapp2.azurewebsites.net`?

Comment: I think you should look at using Blob storage. Much more sensible than writing "to" a webserver.

Comment: @DavidMakogon : I am talking about copying file from `myapp1.azurewebsites.net` to `myapp2.azurewebsites.net` using web service which is stored on `myapp1.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: Ah - that's an important detail (and should have been included in your original question).

Answer (score 0):

Each Web App has its own independent storage, even when hosted on the same App Service Plan. So, you cannot directly copy files between two separate web apps.

Since you mentioned you have a web service running in one of your web apps, there's nothing stopping you from devising a service method where your other web app calls an API to transfer a file. However, this might have performance implications depending on file size.

If it's important to share content between web apps, there are built-in storage options that support this:

- Azure File Storage (essentially an SMB share backed by Azure blob storage). This is durable storage and shareable across web apps.
- Azure blobs. Again, this storage is shareable across web apps, but blobs will require using the Azure Storage REST API (or SDK for your language of choice).

Which method you choose is entirely up to you and your app's design.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, if you want to share some information between the 2 servers then use Azure Queue

Comment: Why an Azure queue? They cannot store an entire file if file size > 64K. So now you have to push content to a blob, then send a queue message.

Comment: @David Makogon Exactly, the queue will be just to notify the other web app that the file has been copied

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to write that file from Azure Server A to Azure Server B.

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could upload your files to the target Web App via FTP. If so, you could follow this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to upload Files with FTP.

**Note:** For the Ftp hostname and credentials, you could log in to the Azure portal, choose your web site, click the Download publish profile link in the Overview page.

Additionally, for a long-term consideration, you'd better store your files in a central position. And it's a ideal approach for sharing files between apps and scaling your Web App. As David said, you could choose Azure File or Azure Blob. And you could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) and [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) for getting started with Azure File & Blob Storage.